# When do i need the IabHelper Class for making an InApp purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

i followed this document http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html to create a test-application, which starts an in-app-purchase procedure, after clicking a button.
I published the application as an alpha release and tested the in-app-purchase  and it works.

My problem is, that i get confused by other in-app-purchase examples. They all use a Class called "IabHelper" to do the in-app-purchase.
But it seems, that one does not need this class to make an in-app-purchase.
The class is even used in the official In-App-Billing V3 "TrivalDrive" example, but it is never mentioned in the in-app-billing guide i posted above.

So could someone please explain to me, why and when i should use the IabHelper class?

Thank you in advance.

Here is a simplified version of the code i use to make an in-app-purchase:

```
private void doPurchase() {
    try {
        Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), "premium.upgrade",
            "inapp", "");

        if (buyIntentBundle != null && buyIntentBundle.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE") == 0) {
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

            startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(),
                Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
        }
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString("productId");
                Log.i(">>>", "You have bought the "
                    + sku
                    + ". Excellent choice, "
                    + "adventurer!");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(">>>", "Failed to parse purchase data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right the Guide is kinda confusing considering the IABHelper. Basically the IAB-Helper is a helper-class written by a Google employee that does a lot of the heavy lifting. So if you use the IAB-Helper you don't have to write as much code as you did in your doPurchase() method. You simply write the following line:

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(activity, sku, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener);
```

Same goes for the stuff after the purchase, no fiddling around with JSON objects

```
if (info.getSku().equals(sku))
    doSomething();
```

Note: You have to setup the mHelper before and implement the various listeners. And of course the IABHelper does exactly the same thing in the background like you did in your methods. It's just another layer of abstraction.

So that's the good news about the IABHelper. The bad news: The IABHelper has some pretty serious bugs which lead to occasional crashes. Though I'd still recommend using it since it catches a bazillion more errors that you can't even think off.

On the following Android Developer Training site you can find a guide which shows how to use the IABHelper pretty good.
https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample

Comment: Dang. It's pretty pathetic that Google can't even write a bug-free implementation of in-app purchasing.

Comment: @trans Yeah it's kinda strange since it is such a fundamental part of the platform. Nevertheless I've been using a library called [Checkout](https://github.com/serso/android-checkout) for quite some time without experiencing any noticeable issues. I highly recommend it for everything IAB related.